# count the number of likes from another model Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

implementing a like model where user could like a pet. If user presses like, isLike would be true while unlike would be isLike is false
Model

```
class pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class likes(models.Model):
    petId = models.ForeignKey(
        "pet", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    liker = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    isLike = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class countlikes(models.Model):
    petId = models.ForeignKey(
        "pet", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    numOfLikes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Serializer

```
class PetSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'


class LikesSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = likes
        fields = '__all__'


class CountlikesSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = countlikes
        fields = '__all__'
```

Viewset

```
class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = pet.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
        # permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = PetSerializer

class LikesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = likes.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
        # permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = LikesSerializer

class CountlikesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = countlikes.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
        # permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = countlikesSerializer
```

what I tried: two get requests to get the Number of likes and if isLike is true or false. If user likes, i would increment the numOfLikes and decrement if user unlikes and then do a put request.

Comment: why not have a number field called 'likecount' inside the pet model, then increment the like count with a like function or the same with a dislike function and a 'dislikecount'.
Whenever you retrieve a Pet, you would see how many likes/dislikes it has according to how many times the like/dislike function has been run on that particular pet by the user.

Comment: Can you share your viewset(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `countlikes` will introduce data duplication in your modeling, and it turns out that keeping data in sync, is harder than it might look. Therefore I advice to remove the `countlikes` model. Especially since it is not a real entity: it is "*pure fabrication*".

You can add two extra fields in your `PetSerializer`:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.IntegerField()
    dislikes = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'likes', 'dislikes')
```

In your `ModelViewSet`, you then should pass a queryset that is *annotated*:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = pet.objects.annotate(
        likes=Coalesce(Sum('likes__isLike'), Value(0)),
        dislikes=Coalesce(Count('likes')-Sum('likes__isLike'), Value(0))
    )
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
```

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Pet` instead of <s>`pet`</s>.

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Like` instead of <s>`likes`</s>.

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
>   will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
>   be `pet`, instead of <s>`petId`</s>.

Comment: How would I keep track to prevent the user from adding more likes to the same pet

Comment: @Xzeta: just make `unique_together = ('petId', 'liker')` in your model. If you then work with a `Form`, it will be done automatically for you. Otherwise you will need to make some routine in the view to handle that.

Comment: what is Coalesce for

Comment: @Xzeta: An SQL database will return `NULL` for `COUNT(..)`s and `SUM(..)`s over empty sets. By `Coalesce`, we convert the `NULL` into a zero.

Comment: so this would count the # of likes when isLike is true?

Comment: @Xzeta: the `likes` is the number of `likes` objects with `isLike=True`, the `dislikes` is the total number of related `likes` objects *without* the number of `likes` objects with `isLike=True` (so with `isLike=False`).

Comment: "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, like, name

Comment: @Xzeta: if you changed the name of your model, you need to change `likes__` to `like__` (in both `Count` and `Sum`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I get the isLike value of an user with PetViewSet? Thanks