# Is there a way to add custom fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating a rest API for my Django blog project and I have models `Post` and `PostLike` models as you below:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField( default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[0:100]

class PostLike(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And I have a `Post` serialiser like

```py
class PostSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    likes_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model= Post
        fields = ['id','text','author', 'approved','created_date', 'likes_count' ]
```

I wish the `likes_count` to be count for the `PostLike` objects with the post of the queried post. What is the right way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) allows you to return a value based on the return value of a class method.

EDIT:
Note that the method accepts the object as a parameter. Therefore to achieve what you want, you can return:

```py
def like_count(self, obj):
    return obj.postlike_set.count()
```

Comment: It worked very well. But I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827382/6842763) answer? Is it also an option?

Comment: Yes it is, but is handled on the view layer. It works by annotating the queryset when getting data from the database.